# Does simulation always show signal/output assignment on clock edge?

Tags: process, signals, vhdl, simulation, fpga

So I understand that if we assign a signal or output in a clocked process that the assignment happens on the falling edge or in other words when a process suspends, but why is it that during simulation signals or outputs get assigned during the rising edge of the clock?
As an example I have the following code:

```
 if(rising_edge(clk)) then
     if(one_second_counter = "10111110101111000001111111")
         one_second_counter <= (others=> '0');
     else
      one_second_counter <= one_second_counter + 1; --
 end if;
```

I have attached simulation waveform:
[image: waveform]

Answer (score 0):

> So I understand that if we assign a signal or output in a clocked process that the assignment happens on the falling edge or in other words when a process suspends…

This is incorrect. The assignment happens when the sensitivity condition for the process is met. In your example, this is `rising_edge(clk)` -- the rising edge of the clock.

Comment: A process with a sensitivity list will resume whenever a condition it's implicit last statement wait statement is sensitive to occurs (`wait on sensitivity_list;`). The outer if statement will only allow execution of the sequential statements within when it's condition evaluates to TRUE, here on the rising edge of clk. IEEE Std 1076-2008  IEEE Standard VHDL Language Reference Manual 11.3 Process statement, 10.2 Wait statement,  10.8 if statement, 10.5 Signal assignment statement/10.5.2 Simple signal assignments and 16.8.4 Signal edge detection. It shows the perils of providing VHDL snippets.